# Suppress hotkey combinations of pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I found this code from the [pynput issues page](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/170) and it works for suppression of single-key hotkeys. In the filter, only one key is detected. How do I apply this for suppressing key combinations such as `Alt+F4`?

```
from pynput import keyboard
 
def keyboard_listener():
    global listener
    def on_press(key):
        print('on press', key)

    def on_release(key):
        print('on release', key)
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            return False # This will quit the listener
 
    def win32_event_filter(msg, data):
        if (msg == 257 or msg == 256) and data.vkCode == 112: # Key Down/Up & F1
            print("Suppressing F1 up")
            listener._suppress = True
            # return False # if you return False, your on_press/on_release will not be called
        else:
            listener._suppress = False
        return True
            
    return keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release,
        win32_event_filter=win32_event_filter,
        suppress=False
    )

listener = keyboard_listener()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with listener as ml:
        ml.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on_press`, `on_release`, and `win32_event_filter` always return a single key in action so you need to check if both buttons are pressed and ignore that action. More detail can be found [here](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20). Here how I can suppressing that key combination:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key
import time

altPressed = False

def on_press(key):
    global altPressed
    altPressed = (key == Key.alt_l)
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        keyboardListener.stop()

def win32_event_filter(msg, data):
    global altPressed
    if data.vkCode == 115 and altPressed: # suppress f4 when alt_l pressed
        print("suppressed f4")
        keyboardListener.suppress_event()

def on_release(key):
    global altPressed
    altPressed = (key == Key.alt_l)

keyboardListener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,  
                                     win32_event_filter=win32_event_filter,
                                     on_release=on_release)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboardListener.start()
    while(keyboardListener.is_alive()):
        time.sleep(1)
```